# While onBackPressed method is called in Webview, it stops caching

Tags: java, android

I am working on a webview project in Android Studio and using android caching system also. It was working well before. Meanwhile, I added the on BackPressed() method to the activity.

As I added the method it stopped caching.

```
`@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}`
```

And now I couldn't cache the webpage. Please suggest the best solution. 
And thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this line

```
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yeah. It was caching perfectly before I add `onBackPressed()` method

Comment: If you only want cache in the Back button, probably just keep it disabled and enable it when Back button is pressed? See this might help [cache android webview](https://web.archive.org/web/20140413233358/http://alex.tapmania.org/2010/11/html5-cache-android-webview.html)

Comment: Solved.. Thanks!